# Find and replace multiple words in a column in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

```
Sub xLator2()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long, i As Long
Dim from(), too()
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '   contains the data
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2") '   contains the translation table

s2.Activate

N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim from(1 To N)
ReDim too(1 To N)
For i = 1 To N
    from(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    too(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

s1.Activate

For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:=too(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

I am using above code to find and replace multiple words (in "Column A Sheet1" with words in "Column B Sheet 2") in below mentioned sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15TRLccDr_EAR8s78u-WGSkGpAecBf42_lhRkjCev_WE/edit?usp=sharing

However when I apply this in another sheet (as mentioned below) for another data then code fails i.e. I get distorted words in sheet1:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ba9pQDjMPWJd4YFpGffhtVcHxml0LdUUVQ0prrOEUY/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me out so that I can replace words in "Column A Sheet1" with words in "Column B Sheet2"

Note: Above links have been given of google spreadsheet however I am having problem in Excel 2007 sheet.

I request you to help me by giving whole revised code as I am not good in VBA

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is to make the replacement once only, and stop further rules once a replacement is made.  Taking your second sheet as an example, line 12 "but" should be translated to "however", and stop further rules so that "however" does not translate to "hoyouever" (as rule #17 translates "we" to "you").

A workaround is to first translate everything to some intermediate symbol, and in the second round translate from the intermediate symbols to the desired replacement.  Slightly modifying your code as below will work:

```
Sub xLator2()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long, i As Long
Dim from(), too()
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '   contains the data
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2") '   contains the translation table

s2.Activate

N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim from(1 To N)
ReDim too(1 To N)
For i = 1 To N
    from(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    too(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

s1.Activate

' -------------- Modification starts here --------------------------
' Replace from from(i) to __MYREPLACEMENTi__  (where i is the counter)
For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__"
Next i
' Replace from __MYREPLACEMENTi__ to too(i)  (where i is the counter)
For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__", Replacement:=too(i)
Next i
' -------------- Modification ends here --------------------------
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Kenneth, above code is working till 20 rows which were mentioned in: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ba9pQDjMPWJd4YFpGffhtVcHxml0LdUUVQ0prrOEUY/edit?usp=sharing       However its again not working in: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1spvZAzxT1kB1bytCQaNQH7tl1DJSpLITYgW6P5dxbQE/edit?usp=sharing which contains total 101 rows. Can you provide something which works for hundreds or thousands of rows at once.

Comment: When you answer then please provide whole code so that I can copy the same.

Comment: Waiting for reply